# Debug with the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I was trying to modify the icon in the manifest file.
Then when I tried to debug, I get the error:

```
The application could not be launched for debugging.
Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked.
```

What I have to do?

Comment: Unlock the screen on the phone. Swipe up or however you unlock your phone...

Comment: No that didn't work. Restarting the emulator was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is also presented here:

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/08/17/top-5-commonly-encountered-issues-and-solutions-using-the-windows-phone-8-emulator.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not debugging with the emulator (as you suggest). You need to change the target device to one of the emulators.